# Problem with the interpretation of "Now" as @Sys.Time in Dialogflow

Tags: time, google-cloud-platform, skype, dialogflow-es

Currently i am creating a chatbot for skype using Dialogflow the main problem is when i use the command "**Now**" in a skype message it uses my current time +1 hour, but when i ask for the time "Now" from the IOS Application it use the current correct TimeZone, someone knows from "where" exactly dialogflow takes the current time zone for the word "**Now**" because from my **app-IOS** because from the IOS_Application it gets one value (Correct timezone value) and from skype it gets a another(timezone + 1 hour value)

**Raw Interaction Log(Dialogflow - Skype):**

```
{
  "queryText": "what time is now?",
  "parameters": {
    "time": "StiDate [Thu Oct 18 12:38:16 CDT 2018]"
  },
  "fulfillmentText": "the time is 12:38:16",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "[{\"type\":0,\"speech\":\"the time is 12:38:16\"}]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    "id": "37524c80-a15a-4c04-aa9b-38986ff38993",
    "displayName": "A_Test_EventTime"
  },
  "languageCode": "en",
  "sentimentAnalysisResult": {},
  "id": "93ce9408-4b73-4f18-9ae0-b947a906afc8",
  "sessionId": "6b69769b-1ce7-4359-9018-c88d017485bf",
  "timestamp": "2018-10-18T17:38:16.164Z",
  "source": "agent"
}
```

**Raw Interaction Log(Dialogflow - AppIOS):**

```
{
  "queryText": "What time is now?",
  "parameters": {
    "time": "StiDate [Thu Oct 18 11:38:00 CST 2018]"
  },
  "fulfillmentText": "the time is 11:38:00",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "[{\"type\":0,\"speech\":\"the time is 11:38:00\"}]"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      "name": "fa75fc39-7c68-47ac-bea5-12394f425855",
      "lifespanCount": 4,
      "parameters": {
        "time.original": "now?",
        "time": "StiDate [Thu Oct 18 11:38:00 CST 2018]"
      }
    }
  ],
  "intent": {
    "id": "37524c80-a15a-4c04-aa9b-38986ff38993",
    "displayName": "A_Test_EventTime"
  },
  "languageCode": "en",
  "sentimentAnalysisResult": {},
  "id": "58ade82b-c842-44b6-b0a2-d6cced4d6648",
  "sessionId": "dfe0efda53d11aa3d8d43e92a726f9e4",
  "timestamp": "2018-10-18T17:38:00.695Z",
  "source": "agent"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow agents have a default time zone.  You can change this time zone in your Dialogflow's agents settings in the console: https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/create-manage#general

Comment: thank you for your answer matthewayne, only one question there is any way to have this date management dynamic like X time for X country? 
Or it should be better to manage it using a webhook instead?

Comment: I think using a webhook is your only option for transforming dates in Dialogflow